# How can I detect if a Discord message contains link?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, discord.js, contains

I am trying to get my bot to detect a message from a specific person. If this message is a link/image/file, I want it to automatically react with the specified emojis.

Everything works correctly, except for the "if message is a link".
This does not seem to work at all. I've tried searching the documentation, and can't seem to find the solution.

Any help is appreciated!

```
client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    if (message.author.id === '217900978756780032') { //works
    if (message.content.includes("https://")) { //does NOT work
    if (message.attachments.size > 0) { //works
        message.react('<:facebook:1009793997872562287>')
        message.react('<a:siren:886047171768635432>')
        
    }}}
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution uses [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to check if a link is an `http[s]` link and validates under these conditions:

- link starts with http
- link has content after the ://

Also, for better practice, you should use [Guard Clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339121/how-do-you-implement-a-guard-clause-in-javascript) as I have inserted into your code below to write cleaner code.

```js
client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    if (message.author.id !== '217900978756780032') return;
    const isLink = new RegExp(/https?:\/\/\S+/g).test(message.content);
    if (!isLink) return;
    if (message.attachments.size > 0) return;

    message.react('<:facebook:1009793997872562287>');
    message.react('<a:siren:886047171768635432>');
});
```

Comment: TypeError: First argument to String.prototype.includes must not be a regular expression
    at String.includes (<anonymous>)

When I replaced the code with yours, the code had no "problems" and the bot started correctly - but when I triggered this script, it crashed with the above mention.

Comment: Check the edit I just posted, I used RegExp.test() instead of includes.